# Parsing Request Payload string

Tags: http-headers, xmlhttprequest

can anyone help me in parsing data from Request Payload string like following one:

7|0|5|https://www.bosscapital.com/app/Basic/|B8CC86B6E3BFEAF758DE5845F8EBEA08|com.optionfair.client.common.services.TradingService|getAssetDailyTicks|J|1|2|3|4|2|5|5|CB|U9mc4GQ|

Thanks & Regards
Ajay

Comment: What do you want as an outcome of your parsing? Do you simply want so split the string at the pipe character? What language are you working with? Please provide more information.

Comment: i just want to get all useful data out of it like sessionID, and other data being passed in the string.

Actually i want to make a request to server through code and need to generate a similar string as mentioned above.

And i am using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `Split()` method on strings to split them at a certain character. Alternatively, you can use `Regex.Split(value, "<pattern>");` for splitting, e.g. if you have multiple characters you want to split at. `<pattern>` is a string here, so you can provide more than one character (e.g. `"\r\n"` to find line breaks).

```
using System;

class Program {

  static void Main() {
    string s = "7|0|5|https://www.bosscapital.com/app/Basic/|B8CC86B6E3BFEAF758DE5845F8EBEA08|com.optionfair.client.common.services.TradingService|getAssetDailyTicks|J|1|2|3|4|2|5|5|CB|U9mc4GQ|";

    // Split string at pipe character
    string[] parts = s.Split('|');

    // Process segments
    foreach (string segment in parts) {
      Console.WriteLine(segment);

      // Use the segmented data...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Fell free to accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you.